# Swift Package Could Not be Resolved

Tags: swift, xcode, neo4j

I was adding the "Theo" [package](https://github.com/Neo4j-Swift/Neo4j-Swift) to my swift project and got the following error. Should I be concerned? I was allowed to add the package anyway, so I'm guessing that it wasn't a critical error?

[image]

EDIT:

The package is also greyed out, which seems problematic.

[image]

Comment: The package dev suggests tagging questions with “Theo”

Comment: I tried, but Stack Overflow said I couldn't use that tag unless I had 1500 rep

Comment: I tried to add it for you but couldn’t as it’s too similar to “Theos” and I’d need to start a discussion on Meta first! Maybe try the Slack channel he mentions?

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for making me aware of it, and pinging me on Github. I'll have a look into it

Comment: Thanks! I'm excited to use the repo!